# Application_error function intermittently catch "File does not exist"

Tags: asp.net, exception, global-asax

I am using the `Application_Error` event for handling the exceptions and it catches almost all exceptions correctly. However in some pages it catches with exception "File does not exist" and I am not able to find from where it exactly occurs. When I comment the `Application_Error` code, surprisingly that web page works fine.

My main concern is how can trace back to the line of code from where it threw to `Application_Error` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hoooo....... just now solved my issue. During my debugging I had put one checkpoint in Appilcation_Error code and when execution reached it I could see the path of an image (path was wrong) which was loading at that time and which causes the exception. :)

Answer (score 15):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` to look at the file path of the missing file.

Answer (score 0):

Right in my case also in Jquery at lots of place used backgroung image uri & that did not exist, thats why this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

To see the problem, on Application_Error event of Global.asax put:

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Console.WriteLine("Application_Error() -> " + ex.Message + "\n\nURL: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, ex);

        if (ex is HttpUnhandledException)
            Context.ClearError(); // System.NullReferenceException
    }
```